# extract, a column with hebrew column name from a csv file, python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I am using pandads read_csv to read a file and extract  specific columns.
I can easily do it with files with latin-letter column names by first identifying the column name with:
x=pd.read_csv('file_name')
print(x).head(0))
and  then picking a column simply by
desired_column= x('desired_conumn_name')

I do not know how to apply this procedure  when the column names are in hebrew.
In this case print(x).head(0))
prints jibrish. even when I identify the (hebrew)  column name,  'מאושפזים' , by using excel, and use it in desired_column= x( 'מאושפזים')

it does not work and responds :
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'מאושפזים'

Example with latin-letters column names  which works well:

```
mob_file='C:\D_on_external_drive\papers\RESEARCH DATASETS\Global_Mobility_Report.csv'
mobility=pd.read_csv(mob_file)
print(mobility.head(0))
vv=mobility['country_region']
```

Example with hebrews column names  which does not work:

```
cov_file='https://data.gov.il/dataset/f54e79b2-3e6b-4b65-a857-f93e47997d9c/resource/e4bf0ab8-ec88-4f9b-8669-f2cc78273edd/download/corona_hospitalization_ver_0033.csv'
covid=pd.read_csv(cov_file)
print(covid.head(0))
uu=covid['מאושפזים']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `python2.7`, try setting the string as unicode

```py
uu=covid[u'מאושפזים'] # note the u
```